# 'Dict' object has no attribute 'loads' error

Tags: python, json

I want to retrieve the last two pieces of data contained in flucs. In this example, I would like to retrieve [5.68] and [5.74]. Firstly, how do I append only the last two pieces of data. Secondly, how do I remove the time stamp that prefaces the data. The code below produces an error. I have imported the json module so this is not an issue.

My code:

```
request2 = requests.get('https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&eventId=1044547&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
json2 = request2.json()
for selection in json2['selections']:
    for price in selection['prices']:
        for fluc in selection['flucs']:
            nlists = json.loads(fluc)
            print(nlists[-2][1])
            print(nlists[-1][1])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

JSON:

```
"selections":[
   {
      "name":"Bolt From The Blue",
      "selectionId":"10242042",
      "competitorId":"655610",
      "result":"3",
      "resultOrdinal":"3rd",
      "flucsKey":"10242042-Average-FixedWin",
      "bestOdds":6,
      "bestOddsBookie":"Bet365",
      "flucs":"[[1597723530,8],[1597724074,7.7],[1597724665,7.55],[1597725240,7.83],[1597725495,7.85],[1597781362,5.66],[1597781902,4.87],[1597782326,4.75],[1597789022,4.65],[1597790084,4.62],[1597790149,4.61],[1597790624,4.6],[1597794675,4.54],[1597794891,4.52],[1597797663,4.53],[1597797695,4.56],[1597797719,4.58],[1597798687,4.6],[1597799682,4.65],[1597799691,4.66],[1597799695,4.68],[1597799705,4.69],[1597799728,4.7],[1597799743,4.68],[1597799752,4.7],[1597799771,4.69],[1597799797,4.71],[1597799938,4.72],[1597799965,4.73],[1597799996,4.75],[1597800021,4.77],[1597800030,4.78],[1597800050,4.77],[1597800074,4.78],[1597800079,4.79],[1597800084,4.8],[1597800094,4.81],[1597800099,4.82],[1597800111,4.83],[1597800115,4.85],[1597800124,4.86],[1597800129,4.87],[1597800147,4.91],[1597800152,4.97],[1597800161,5.02],[1597800166,5.06],[1597800171,5.25],[1597800180,5.3],[1597800185,5.34],[1597800190,5.39],[1597800196,5.43],[1597800200,5.56],[1597800210,5.6],[1597800215,5.64],[1597800220,5.66],[1597800229,5.68],[1597800239,5.63],[1597800257,5.68],[1597800272,5.63],[1597800285,5.68],[1597800290,5.69],[1597800368,5.68],[1597800508,5.74]]
```

Comment: Somewhere, you assigned a dict object to the variable `json`

Comment: In addiction, don't expose your APIKey in a public site like this

Comment: It seems that you asked more or less the same yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63462950/how-to-retrieve-the-last-two-pieces-of-data-in-a-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve the last two pieces of data in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63462950/how-to-retrieve-the-last-two-pieces-of-data-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `selection["flucs"]` doesn't return a list but a str, so, you need to convert to an actual list.

Furthermore, you are trying to load it as a json, which is not either valid.

Try the following to inspect your data and figure out what you need to extract:

```
endpoint_url = "YOUR_URL"
request2 = requests.get(endpoint_url,
                    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
json2 = request2.json()
for selection in json2['selections']:
    for price in selection['prices']:
        for fluc in eval(selection['flucs']):
            print(fluc)
```